# SPSS function spssOpenWrite returned error code SPSS_FILE_OERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net, spss

Been using the opensource library from http://spss.codeplex.com/ to create spss files for quit sometime, but now the following error pops up on the creation of a SPSS file.

SPSS function spssOpenWrite returned error code SPSS_FILE_OERROR

```
 public static void createSpss(Enquete eq)
    {       
        if (File.Exists(eq.titel + ".sav"))
        {
            File.Delete(eq.titel + ".sav");
        }
        SpssDataDocument doc = SpssDataDocument.Create(eq.titel + ".sav");
        createMetaData(doc, eq);
        if (doc.Variables.Count != 0)
        {
            createData(doc, eq);
        }
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Anyone got any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to write/update for this location